# Compiling C++ code with GCC on mac os m1 in sublime gives warning

Tags: c++, gcc, homebrew, sublimetext

dylib (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0/lib/gcc/11/libstdc++.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.4) than being linked (11.0) whenever I compile any c++ or c code I get this warning my gcc installed version is g++-11 can anyone tell me how to fix this warning?

Comment: This looks like a homebrew issue.

Comment: The `C++ Single File` build system that ships with Sublime executes `g++` to compile, so it's up to `g++` to know what to do. The same is true if you have created a custom build system in place of the one that ships with Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem you need to update gcc.

If you have homebrew installed then just run `brew upgrade gcc` on you favourite terminal. It worked for me!